# Using wildcards on interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface, bounded-wildcard

Consider the following classes:

```
interface Notifiable {

}

class NotifiableImpl1 implements Notifiable {

}

class NotifiableImpl2 implements Notifiable {

}

class NotifiableImpl3 implements Notifiable {

}
```

It is normal that the following code works:

```
Set<Notifiable> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new NotifiableImpl1());
set.add(new NotifiableImpl2());
set.add(new NotifiableImpl3());
```

However, the following code does not work:

```
Set<? extends Notifiable> set2 = new HashSet<>();
set2.add(new NotifiableImpl1());
set2.add(new NotifiableImpl2());
set2.add(new NotifiableImpl3());
```

I understand it does not work, because it should only be possible to add *one concrete subtype* of `Notifiable` to `set2`, but how does it come then, that the following code also does not work?

```
Set<? extends Notifiable> set2 = new HashSet<>();
set2.add(new NotifiableImpl1());
```

And maybe more interesting, why *does* the following work?

```
Set<Notifiable> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new NotifiableImpl1());
set.add(new NotifiableImpl2());
set.add(new NotifiableImpl3());

Set<? extends Notifiable> set3 = set;
```

Comment: I think you can found answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs). I like this statements `1st use an extends wildcard when you only get values out of a structure
use a super wildcard when you only put values into a structure
and don’t use a wildcard when you both get and put.`

Comment: @nachokk This question is not about super vs extends. While the answer could potentially be similar, it is does not mean that the question is similar.

Comment: That's true, it's not the same question but the same explanation as an answer.

Comment: Pinched from the mentioned thread
"You actually cannot add anything to a Collection<? extends Thing>, because you cannot know at runtime which specific subtype of Thing the collection holds."

Comment: You can do `Set<? extends Bar> set2 = new HashSet< Notifiable >()`, `Set<? extends Bar> set2 = new HashSet<NotifiableImpl3>()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first code is perfectly valid. Since you can have a reference of super type hold a subclass object as in below assignment:

```
Notifiable notifiable = new NotifiableImpl1();
```

The same way you can add a `NotifiableImpl` object to a `Set<Notifiable>`. That set can hold object of any subtype.

Second code is not valid as per the [PECS rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/1679863). Basically a `Set<? extends Notifiable>` is a producer of `Notifiable`, and not a consumer. You can't add any subtype object to it. That set can actually hold a reference to a `HashSet<NotifiableImpl1>`, and you can't add a `NotifiableImpl2` object to such set. It would fail at runtime, if it was allowed by compiler. In fact you can't add anything except `null` to such types, because the actual type that the `Set` will hold is still unknown to the compiler.

Third code is also valid. A `Set<? extends Notifiable>` means a `Set` of an unknown type that extends from `Notifiable`. So, in the following code:

```
Set<Notifiable> set = new HashSet<>();
Set<? extends Notifiable> set3 = set;
```

You're simply assigning a concrete parameterized type reference to a bounded wildcard type. Since `Notifiable` is a valid substitute for `? extends Notifiable`, that assignment perfectly makes sense.

The reason behind existence of the wildcard types is to allow a single reference point to different kinds of objects. This is the general polymorphic rule. Without wildcard it won't be valid for a `Set<Notifiable>` to point to a `HashSet<NotifiableImpl1>`, simply because generic types are invariant.